# Error: no CustomApplication named standard__LightningInstrumentation found

Tags: deployment

When I am trying to deploy (using ant) to my sandbox I am keep getting the many of the following errors:
profiles/... - App Subscription User.profile -- Error: In field: application - no CustomApplication named standard__LightningInstrumentation found (line 78, column 30)

permissionsets/... -- Error: In field: application - no CustomApplication named standard__LightningInstrumentation found

How can I solve it?

Comment: you need to include standard__LightningInstrumentation in your package.xml

Comment: package.xml - Entity type: 'standard__LightningInstrumentation' is unknown

Comment: You need to first retrieve this from your sandbox or if you don’t want to deploy this app, open your user profile.xml and remove reference

Comment: I'm having the same issue when deploying a profile unchanged from one Winter '18 org to another identical one - seems like a new bug in the metadata API.

Comment: I have just run into this issue after my sandboxes where refreshed from Prod and then the release of Winter 20 was released to Prod and the sandbox was updated as well, but I can see that the 'Lightning Usage App' is missing from my sandboxes. My API version is also on 46.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and updated the API version to 45.0 in the package.xml file and it worked.

Comment: Hello Jason, Welcome to SFSE!! Please Post your question in detail.

Answer (score 1):

When this happens you can, using the CLI, get the id of the object in question using `sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "Select Id, MemberName From SourceMember Where MemberType = 'CustomApplication'" -t`.  Then use the Id from that query like below.

`sfdx force:data:record:delete -s SourceMember -i 0MZ0x000001eqiJGAQ -t`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an error similar to this when I was playing with my scratch org, pulled metadata to local, deleted metadata from the scratch org, pulled again, but my profile, for some odd reason, didn't sync with local. When I tried pushing to another scratch org, the error popped up.

In short, my profile sees remnant stuff that are non-existent, that's why the error was thrown.

If you're not trying to install a custom application named `standard__LightningInstrumentation`, then I suggest this fix:

1. go into the profile
2. search for the tag `applicationVisibilities` where the child tag `application`'s  value is `standard__LightningInstrumentation`
3. delete it

It fixed my error. Hope it fixes yours.