# Permission Set X of Type PermissionSet failed to deploy due to In field: application - no CustomApplication named standard__Work found

Tags: deployment, devopscenter

While deploying I am getting this error

> Permission Set X of Type PermissionSet failed to deploy due to In field: application - no CustomApplication named standard__Work found

I understand that the org in which the permission set is being deployed does not have this standard app. I am not able to ascertain which is this app so that I can either I can remove or add it as appropriate.

I check Application Manager between the two orgs and the developer instance has additional app Studio Analytics but its API name is 'Insights' which seems irrelevant to the error.

I tried searching and found only this link https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8NsASAV

This link does not have a solution.

Comment: related? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227818/error-no-customapplication-named-standard-lightninginstrumentation-found

Comment: Thanks @cropredy. Eventually, I had to delete the applicationVisibilities from the permission set XML.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce Support confirmed that the standard__Work app is added due to a bug. Product bug: W-3848813.

Since we are using DevOps center we were interested in knowing what we are adding that is causing this issue.

Our solution now is to remove the standard__Work from the applicationVisibilities of the permission set. T
This we have to do every time we commit this particular permission set from the dev ops center.